# Need a Function that allows parameters to pass as argument for logic inside the function in Greenplum

Tags: functions, plpgsql

Suppose I have a query :-

```
select 'public.test123 is' || ' ' || quote_literal(obj_description('public.test123'::regclass)) || ';' as test;
            test
-------------------------------------
     public.test123 is 'dog';
(1 row)
```

I want to create a function named `comment` that will help me pass the schema_name and table-name(public and test123) as in above query, and provide me the above output.

And then insert this output to another table public.entries with the table name passed and output of the query in comment column like below-

```
select * from public.entries;
table_name | comment
------------+---------
public.test123 | public.test123 is 'dog';
(1 rows)
```

and return the function with SUCCESS.

```
Output like:-

select comment('public','test123');
           test
-------------------------------------
     SUCCESS
```

Comment: It seems you have nearly everything to write that function.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @dezso Can you help me create this function?